Is it possible to display a timeseries graph based on an existing dashboard containing multiple Loki log message queries?
We currently have a dashboard that displays error+ log messages in 1 panel, and rate of error+ messages in a timeseries graph.
Our graph only displays error count from our original log query we set the dashboard up with, but we've since added multiple queries to the log message panel so that it displays messages from multiple systems.
Is it possible to display a timeseries showing log message rate based on the log message panel?  I've tried adding a new timeseries panel using the "Dashboard" source, and the log message panel a the query, but it displayed the messages "Data is missing a number field".  I've looked for a transform to apply that counts over time, but I can't seem to find the one I want.
Or is there another way to set up the log message panel and graph visualisation to both be driven from the same query in some other way?
Here are our queries…
The timeseries graph…
sum by (extra_server) (
    count_over_time(
        (
            {filename="/applogs/error.log",job="applogs"}
            | json
            | level_name =~ `(${level:pipe})`
        )
        [10s]
    )
)

The log messages…
{filename="/applogs/error.log",job="applogs"}
| label_format log_stream=`LEGACY`
| log_stream =~ `(${logStream:pipe})`
| json
| level_name =~ `(${level:pipe})`
| label_format tenant=`{{ regexReplaceAll "\\..*$" .extra_server "" }}`
| line_format `{{.tenant}} {{.log_stream}} [{{ .level_name }}] {{ regexReplaceAll "\n(\r|\n|.)*$" .message "" }}`

---

{filename="/applogs/error.log",job="applogs"}
| label_format log_stream=`LEGACY`
| log_stream =~ `(${logStream:pipe})`
| json
| level_name =~ `(${level:pipe})`
| label_format tenant=`{{ regexReplaceAll "\\..*$" .extra_server "" }}`
| line_format `{{.tenant}} {{.log_stream}} [{{ .level_name }}] {{ regexReplaceAll "\n(\r|\n|.)*$" .message "" }}`

---

{swarm_service=~"apiv2-.+_php"}
| label_format log_stream=`APIv2`
| log_stream =~ `(${logStream:pipe})`
| json
| level_name =~ `(${level:pipe})`
| line_format "{{.extra_tenant}} {{.log_stream}} [{{.level_name}}] {{.message}}"

---

{swarm_service=~"apiv2-.+_worker"}
| label_format log_stream=`APIv2 WORKER`
| log_stream =~ `(${logStream:pipe})`
| json
| level_name =~ `(${level:pipe})`
| line_format "{{.extra_tenant}} {{.log_stream}} [{{.level_name}}] {{.message}}"

---

{swarm_service="ironman_php"}
| label_format log_stream=`IRONMAN PHP`
| log_stream =~ `(${logStream:pipe})`
| json
| level_name =~ `(${level:pipe})`
| line_format "{{.extra_tenant}} {{.log_stream}} [{{.level_name}}] {{.message}}"

Thanks in advance.
